# Logger name in each java class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am replacing an old logging system in my java application with `log4j2` .
I am a little confused with logger names. Is the logger name the same thing that we define in the xml file and should that be the same as the argument for `logmanager.getlogger (arg)` ?

I also do not know whether I should define loggers on top of each class and should they have different names? 
For example there is a package `login` and `login.ui .`

Login has 5 files (classes) inside and ui too. I would like to log the whole login package. But I have problems on how to define the `loggers` and where on the java file and what patterns should there be for the logger names.

`Logger logger = logmanager.getlogger( ? )`

Can the `Logger` object have the same name in each file?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe having a look in the [API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) or in the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Logger_hierarchy) already answer your question.

Comment: Can the Logger object have the same name in each file? - Yes  
_Should_ the Logger object have the same name in each file? - No

Comment: "Should the Logger object have the same name in each file? - No" - because you cannot see in the logfile where the output came from by loggers' names. Sometimes this can make sense, though. I used it for example for tracking MessageObjects through an API, so I could turn that part of logging on/off/verbose independently from "normal" app logging.

Comment: The thing is I use different file for logging each package. I am having problems now and I am asking that if I can use
 Logger logger*  LogManager.getLogger( MyClass.class ) on each of my classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger( YourClassName.class )
```

If you only have setup a root logger, this already will show up messages from there.
If you want to have loggers from a specific package to be configured differently from rootlogger (e.g. different log level), then you have to create a logger named like that package in the config of log4j2. You can refer to the log4j2 configuration manual about how to do this.

All classes in that package and subsequent packages will be mapped to that logger.

Example:

Config has root logger and logger "my.package"

Then loggers created with `LogManager.getLogger( YourClass.class )` where YourClass is in package `my.package` or in some package `my.package.xyz` will use logger "my.package".
Loggers created with for example `LogManager.getLogger( "SPECIALLOGGER" )` or `LogManager.getLogger( OtherPackageClass.class )` where OtherPackageClass is in package "my.otherpackage" will fall back to root logger.

I also recommend to have a look into the [log4j manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I have nested packages, I still use LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class) on top of every single java file ?

Comment: I used to import the logger from one of the files in the package, to the other files and use  the same thing.

Comment: That's the recommended way to do that (static logger for each class). That way you can later still add a logger config for the sub-package without touching the source code.

Comment: But can all the files in a package use the same logger ? I mean I import it to the other files. I am wondering if my problem is from this. 
So on top of each class can all the Loggers be **logger** or different names like logger1 logger2, .. ?

Comment: No, just name them logger. That's fine. It's just a label. You could call them "gary" haha ...

Answer (score -1):

Look at project [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html) to use simple annotations instead of declaring logger variables.